# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection.The connection's current state is closed:while using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am currently developing a asp.net web application, and for the better usage purpose I am using **stored procedure** along with **business layer and presentation layer**.
I have written a class in a Presentation layer which is shown below which returns a value from database.

```
 public string fnselectrole(UserMaster ua)
 {
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(str);
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("selectrole", Con);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id", ua.UserName);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string role = "";
    while (reader.Read())
        {

            ua.Role = (string)reader["Role_Id"];
            role = ua.Role.ToString();
        }

    Con.Close();
    return role;


}
```

This is a **business layer** where in the class is been called,Here it will throw exception as shown above.i **googled** the error and find out that this error will only come when connection is not opned neither closed,I have checked with those error  and still I am getting  the **same error**.

```
  public string fnselectrole(UserMaster ua)
 {
    Connection connect1 = new Connection();
    try
    {
        return connect1.fnselectrole(ua);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        connect1 = null;
    }

}
```

Stored procedure query:

```
 use [RHK_HIS1] 
 go


 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectrole]
 @User_Id varchar(10)
 AS
 BEGIN

 select role_M.Role_Id from Role_M,User_M where User_M.User_Id = Role_M.Role_Id and User_M.User_Id = @User_Id

 END
 GO
```

Comment: Should it be `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` or `SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();`. Notice `Cmd` vs `cmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remember that every Data reader requires a different connection. To use a datareader you:

1. Declare a connection
2. open that connection
3. execute the datareader
4. close the datareader

   SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 1):

If you have `cmd` defined at a more global level, then problem could be `cmd` vs `Cmd`

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

It should be:

```
SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
```